# Validación De campos vacíos y bloqueo de un boton

Tags: javascript, html

Necesito que me valide los campos vacios y en ese caso me bloquee el botón

Aquí está mi código

```html
<form action="/action_page.php">
First name: <input type="text" name="FirstName" value="Mickey"><br>
Last name: <input type="text" name="LastName" value="Mouse"><br>
<input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

Su usas `html5` te bastaría añadir el atributo `required` a tus `inputs`. Con eso el propio HTML valida que estos campos **no** estén vacíos.

```html
<form>
First name: <input type="text" required name="FirstName" value=""><br>
Last name: <input type="text" required name="LastName" value=""><br>
<input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Después para bloquear el botón debes hacerlo con Javascript y ya tienes varias opciones:

Mira [esta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6658937/how-to-check-if-a-form-is-valid-programmatically-using-jquery-validation-plugin) y [esta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12470622/how-can-i-check-the-validity-of-an-html5-form-that-does-not-contain-a-submit-but) a ver cual te convence más. Y ya dentro de la lógica de la función puedes agregar tu `alert` si así lo deseas.

Saludos

Comment: Esta solucion esta bien, pero en este caso el usuario esta pidiendo un alert.

Comment: He modificado la respuesta, añadiendo lo del `alert`. Tu solución también es buena, quizá le guste hacer un mixin de lo que hemos aportado ;)

Comment: Ahora esta mejor, el unico problema que le veo a tu respuesta es que solo funcionaria para html5 pero es bastante mas elegante de lo que yo he hecho

Comment: Creo que el atributo `required` no es suficiente para validar un campo. intencionalmente inspeccionando elemento se le puede `borrar` dicho atributo y no habría validación.

Comment: @Dev.Joel Si es suficiente o no depende del grado de seguridad que se requiera. La pregunta no incluye alguna con respecto al grado de validación ni da pistas de que se requiera prevenir las modificaciones por parte del código fuente de la página por parte usuario.

Comment: @Ruben si busca validar es obvio que desea seguridad. La respuesta dice **bastaria** y no basta con solo eso.

Comment: @Dev.Joel: Por favor observa que yo hablé de "grado de seguridad". Cuando dices que es obvio que desea seguridad y que no basta con lo propuesto ¿A qué grado/nivel/robustes de seguridad te refieres?

Comment: Como Dev. Supongo que al más alto grado o una seguridad a medias prefiere usted?  En fin si es validación prefiero que sea el más alto grado. Puede diferir con esto, pero bueno son puntos de vista.

Answer (score 1):

Con esto te da una alerta si tienes algun campo vacio.

```js
function validar(){
  var validado = true;
  elementos = document.getElementsByClassName("inputFormu");
  for(i=0;i<elementos.length;i++){
    if(elementos[i].value == "" || elementos[i].value == null){
    validado = false
    }
  }
  if(validado){
  window.location = "/action_page.php";
  }else{
  alert("Hay campos vacios")   
  }
}
```

```html
<form action="javascript:validar()" >
  First name: <input class="inputFormu" type="text" name="FirstName" ><br>
  Last name: <input class="inputFormu" type="text" name="LastName" ><br>
  <input id="boton"  type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Si quieres que el boton este bloqueado dependiendo de si hay los inputs estan vacios o no, lo que deberias hacer es basicamente lo mismo, pero en vez de que la funcion validar se ejecute cuando envias el form, que se ejucute con un `keyup` en cada uno de los inputs.

De esta manera, en la segunda solucion no te permite enviar el formulario haste que los campos tengan datos.

```js
function validar(){
  var validado = true;
  elementos = document.getElementsByClassName("inputFormu");
  for(i=0;i<elementos.length;i++){
    if(elementos[i].value == "" || elementos[i].value == null){
    validado = false
    }
  }
  if(validado){
  document.getElementById("boton").disabled = false;
  
  }else{
     document.getElementById("boton").disabled = true;
  //Salta un alert cada vez que escribes y hay un campo vacio
  //alert("Hay campos vacios")   
  }
}
```

```html
<form>
  First name: <input onkeyup="validar()" class="inputFormu" type="text" name="FirstName" ><br>
  Last name: <input onkeyup="validar()" class="inputFormu" type="text" name="LastName" ><br>
  <input id="boton"  type="submit" value="Submit" disabled>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
var campo1 = document.getElementById("campo1");
if(campo1.length == 0){
    alert("campo requerido");
    campo1.focus();
    return;
}
```

Haz ese mismo código para cada campo. Y por cada campo vació que dejes te tirara un mensaje y hará un focus al campo vació. Obligando al usuario a llenarlo. Espero te halla servido de algo.

Comment: Hola aunque respondes a la pregunta de forma incompleta, creo que puedes esforzarte un poco más para hacer una mejor respuesta, el enfoque que das no es nada óptimo, procura orientarte a la reutilización de código. No usen alerts no es una buena práctica para los sitios actuales. Y no uses snipets si no corren bien.

Comment: Muchas gracias Luis tu correccion ha sido acatada. Soy nuevo en stackoverflow. Solo tengo 2 dias.

Answer (score 0):

Aquí te dejo un código que hace estrictamente lo que solicitas en tu pregunta, sin tocar tu código **html**, la única condición es que debes incluir (y tal vez ya lo haces) el uso de [jQuery](http://jquery.com), una herramienta que te ayuda a desarrollar mas escribiendo menos como te muestro en el siguiente ejemplo:

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
 $("input[type=text]").on("keyup",function () {
  option=false;
  $("input[type=text]").each(function () {
   if (!this.value) {
    option=true;
   }
  });
    $("input[type=submit]").attr("disabled",option);
 });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form action="/action_page.php">
First name: <input type="text" name="FirstName" value="Mickey"><br>
Last name: <input type="text" name="LastName" value="Mouse"><br>
<input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```